# Inject and use a service in angular module's factory

Tags: angular, typescript, sentry

The angular app uses  sentry to capture exceptions. Sentry is provided using a factory. I am trying to use a service within that factory but can not figure out why I am getting this error:

```
ERROR in/sfsfsadsf/src/app/app.module.ts(64,12): error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

The rest of the code:

```
  //Other imports
import {SentryCaptureErrorService}        from '@common/app/services/sentry-capture-error.service';


export class RavenErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

 constructor(
   public sentryCaptureErrorService: SentryCaptureErrorService
 ) {
 }

  RavenErrorHandler(error: any): void {    
    this.sentryCaptureErrorService.sendCapturedException(error, environment, 'app.module')
  }
}

export function provideErrorHandler() {
  if (
    environment.envName === 'local'
  ) {
    return new ErrorHandler();
  } else {
    return new RavenErrorHandler();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [],
  providers: [
        {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useFactory: provideErrorHandler,
      deps: [SentryCaptureErrorService],
      multi: true,
    },    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})

export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    private sentryCaptureErrorService: SentryCaptureErrorService
  ) {
    this.sentryCaptureErrorService.configAndInstallSentry(environment);
  }

}
```

By including 'sentryCaptureErrorService' in RavenErrorHandler I get the error mentioned above. I can inject the service into AppModule class but not in RavenErrorHandler.

Comment: inside your provideErrorHandler function. Doesn't your `return new RavenErrorHandler();` expects a constructor prop to be passed to it?

Comment: Why are you providing a dep that isn't used?

Comment: @FranciscoSantorelli what would the constructor prop be?

Comment: a `SentryCaptureErrorService` instance, if I'm right.

Comment: And then what do I add in the RavenErrorHandler class? @FranciscoSantorelli

Comment: oh boy. Here you will need to call factory and do that by hand, or make the function that chooses what to return a service so Angular can be injected the sentry service. There are several roads for this but I don't have a clear path for them right now. I'm gonna give it a thought